# Is there any direct method to just output in console in Informatica?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have been trying to find some ways to have a transformation/task like thing that just outputs in console when I run workflows in informatica. There are multiple indirect ways to do it by starting a debugger or seeing the session log but that too is time consuming.

Is there any direct way to just check the output in the console without a target like tlogRow in Talend ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I did it as a workaround below via a reusable java transformation (as the only valid way I could do some data manipulation beforehand running the workflows and also could see my data flow in sort of a message though in session log or by calling a generateRow()
API method to create rows in form of a file that goes by the standard programming in general).

Here is the sample code that I can have on compilation

[image]

and Finally in the output I could see the data as

[image]

Comment: If all you wanted to see is the data in session log, you could've changed the logging to "Verbose Data".

Comment: I din wanted to only see the detailing of the data flow but to see if I could do some data manipulation too like I did via java transformation I can compile my code on doing data manipulation beforehand seeing my data in session log. You actually got my query right though expression had limitions to data manipulation I felt I could do more in java transdormation

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to Evaluate Expression and check the result of what you've built:

[image: Evaluate Expression]

But I'm afraid that's the only thing you get while developing. You need to start the debugger to work with live data. Once debugging, you can use this feature as well with the data in the process - just right click a transformation and choose `Evaluate Expression`.

Answer (score -2):

If i understand correctly, you want to check whether the data is correctly flowing at each component in a mapping by performing intermittent checks while the workflow/mapping execution? Unfortunately as per my knoweldge, informatica powercenter doesnt have any such functionality. Ab-Initio has such component called watchers in GDE which can be created at random locations in a plan/graph.

Regards
Sharath

Answer (score -2):

I don't think there is such a thing as a console other than the session log, but as a workaround, you can create a file target and output stuff there. This also allows you to check the data more or less the way you want.